# How to make C++ Dynamic Library work with React Native

Tags: android, c++, react-native

I'm working on native android videochat application. We use Java and C++ dynamic libs(.so). And recently we started thinking about moving some parts of the application to React Native. The problem is - I don't know the right way to do it. I've read some articles about this, they all using Djinni and C++ source code(cpp and hpp files) not dynamic libraris. I have managed to use dynamic libraries inside java code following this guide: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html

I'm now able to call lib's functions from Java React Modules and I'm using them in React Native JS code. Also libs must work all the time while the application is running and I need to register some Java Objects in Jni to receive callbacks from it. So the final question is - is using Java -> C++ libs -> JS and backwards is good solution? And is there anything I should know about this interaction.